# MongoDB Duplicate Entry

Tags: mongodb

I have the following schema

```
var customerSchema = new Schema({
    customerID: String,
    phoneNumber: String
})

customerSchema.path('customerID').validate(function (customerID, next) {
    Customer.findOne({customerID: customerID}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return next(false);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return next(true); //Valid
        } else {
            return next(false);
        }
    });
}, 'customerID Already Exists');
```

This works perfectly when I was trying to add the same customerID. It will not let me. But previously I tried to press the ADD button at the  **same** time on **different** computer. Somehow the same customerID gets added.

How to prevent such edge cases from happening? I am using MongoLab. Does the latency present a big problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible to have this type of behavior:

```
Press add button on computer1
Press add button on computer2
Validation occurs for the first add and the customer does not exist
Validation occurs for the second add BEFORE the first insert is done and the customer does not yet exist
Both adds succeed
```

You can put a unique constraint on the field at the database level to prevent this - https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

Depending on your needs, you can also have an "upsert" that updates or inserts a new record. In your case, if you're concerned about two users creating a new user with the same ID, just put an index on it at the database.

Comment: Thank you! Also, it seems to not that "These constraints prevent applications from inserting documents that have duplicate values for the inserted fields." What do I need to do for "update"? Lets say I want to update customerID. How do i prevent it from updating to the same customerID. Must I manually findOne and check before update?

Comment: In addition, what is the point of validation? If we can use unique index? It the type of behavior you stated did occur, how will the database return the message?

Comment: You can validate other types of rules like a name matches a certain pattern. The database will return some constraint violated exception but you can handle that and return whatever message you want.